# Unparseable date: "Sat Nov 02 2013 00:15:00"

Tags: java, simpledateformat

for some unknown reason this code throws an **Unparseable date exception**

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Thanks!

```
import java.text.DateFormat
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

String dateString  =                       "Sat Nov 02 2013 00:15:00"

SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss");
Date result =  df.parse(dateString);
System.out.println(result);
```

Screenshot how this code is run

[image]

Comment: Why post code that won't compile? It gives the impression you didn't really try it, and makes it harder for people to help you.

Comment: Thanks for your remarks, I added a screenshot how the code is compiled an run. GroovyConsole is an excellent tool for running java snippets. There are many many posts about date parsing problems using, but I couldn't find one with short notice that solved this particular problem.

Comment: @user955732 That may be, but this is not a standard tool used by those who answer questions. This is why it is recommended to post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat%28java.lang.String%29) you're using use the default date format symbols for your default [Locale](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html).

I suppose that your default Locale doesn't spell months in English. Hence, you should specify an English one :

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
```

Output (with a `fr_FR` default Locale):

> Sat Nov 02 00:15:00 CET 2013